# Materialize CSS Custom Form Validation Error Message

Tags: jquery, html, validation, materialize

everyone! I'm trying to create my registration form using Materialize CSS and jQuery Validation plugin (https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Just wanted to know how do I put the custom error messages that I had set for each validation rule in the plugin into the data-error attribute of the input element?

According to Materialize CSS's Documentation (http://materializecss.com/forms.html), we can add custom validation error messages by adding data-error attribute to our input field labels. But this only shows ONE message for any validation rules that are broken.

I want to display the appropriate error message for the specific validation rule that the user breaks.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="reg-form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="firstname" name="fname" type="text"/>
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="lastname" name="lname" type="text">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required/>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="password" name="pass" type="password" required/>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="confirm-password" name="confirm_pass" type="password" required/>
        <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 right-align">
        <button class="btn btn-large" type="submit" name="action">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my validate method:

```
$("#reg-form").validate({
rules: {
    fname: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    },
    lname: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    },
    mobile_num: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email:true
    },
    pass: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    },
    confirm_pass: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        equalTo: "#pass"
    }
},
//For custom messages
messages: {
    fname: {
        required: "Please enter your first name.",
        minlength: "You sure you're named with one letter?"
    },
    lname: {
        required: "Please enter your last name.",
        minlength: "You sure you're named with one letter?"
    },
    email: {
        required: "Please enter your email address.",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address."
    },
    pass: {
        required: "Please enter a password.",
        minlength: "Password must be atleast 5 characters."
    },
    confirm_pass: {
        required: "Please confirm your password.",
        minlength: "Password must be atleast 5 characters.",
        equalTo: "Password does not match."
    }
}
});
```

Or is there another way of displaying the custom error messages into the validation message label of the input element in Materialize?

Answer (score 5):

There is a section called Custom Error and Success Messages in [Materialize's documentation](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html).

What you should use is the data-error attribute placed on the label.

```
<label for="firstname" data-error="Please enter your first name.">First Name</label>
```

Of course if you want to make the message dynamic you need to use some more logic, but the message needs to go in the data-error attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: any idea how to do this in jquery? what if I want to error when the input is if else in my function

Answer (score 0):

just add required="" or required to the input and it should work just fine

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you please elaborate maybe with short example?

Comment: @mpaskov It's okay if he doesn't. I don't need to try it to know that it's not what I'm looking for. Hahah.

Comment: @RonneilPetterson I guessed as much but maybe there is something we are missing, which would need further explanation.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I made a pen as an example: [link] http://codepen.io/tdurant72/pen/vgyBjZ

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to this to your method :

```
    errorElement: 'div',
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    var placement = $(element).data('error');
    if (placement) {
        $(placement).append(error)
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [materialize 1.0.0 documentation](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) you need to add a tag `span` with the `data-error` and `data-success` attributes after the tag `label`.

```html
<div class="input-field inline">
  <input id="email_inline" type="email" class="validate">
  <label for="email_inline">Email</label>
  <span class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Helper text</span>
</div>
```